# versioning in python flask application

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a flask based web app in which I need to version. However, my project depends upon multiple packages that I put in `requirements.txt` and use `virtual env` to create a working setup.

My question is: if between two versions, I want to change a package that introduced a breaking change - how should I be doing it? I'll be using `nginx` web server (if it can help)

E.g.

1/ I initially create `v1` with package `a`. Package `a` helps me in generating response

2/ I version my api to `v2` that upgrades `a` to `a1` and `a1` has breaking changes -- so, how should I maintain both the version in the same codebase when the depend upon non-compatible versions of packages?

PS: if above is solved, I can simply use `blueprint` to create versioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you only can generate the desired views with different versions of dependencies, you should create two Flask applications.

In `nginx` you need to create different location sections for your two applications, depending on the path, ie route `/v1` to application a, and `/v2` to application b.